# How pandas calculates correlation between categorical variables and continuous variables?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe something like below:

```
age sex     bmi      children   smoker  region      charges

19  female  27.900   0          yes     southwest   16884.92400
18  male    33.770   1          no      southeast   1725.55230
28  male    33.000   3          no      southeast   4449.46200
33  male    22.705   0          no      northwest   21984.47061
32  male    28.880   0          no      northwest   3866.85520
```

I want to calculate correlation between sex and smoker, both are categorical variables. I tried calulating the correlation between sex and smoker using df.corr(), it came out 0.076185

I also tried using cramer's V rule using:

```
def cramers_v(x, y):
    confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(x,y)
    chi2 = chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]
    n = confusion_matrix.sum().sum()
    phi2 = chi2/n
    r,k = confusion_matrix.shape
    phi2corr = max(0, phi2-((k-1)*(r-1))/(n-1))
    rcorr = r-((r-1)**2)/(n-1)
    kcorr = k-((k-1)**2)/(n-1)
    return np.sqrt(phi2corr/min((kcorr-1),(rcorr-1)))

cramers_v(df["sex"], df["smoker"])
0.06914461040709625
```

It is not very clear in the source code that how it calculates the correlation between all the possible combination of categorical and continous variables.

Comment: `df.corr()` actually skips non-numerical columns. How did you get a correlation of sex and smoker?

Comment: What is `chi2_contingency`? This [scipy function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.contingency.chi2_contingency.html)? Imports are part of the script and should be included in the code.

Comment: sex and smoker correlation is calculated after converting them to numeric values using LabelEncoder and then running `df.corr()` . My question is this the correct way to do that?

Comment: No, it is not the correct way. If you assign arbitrary values to categories then all the subsequent calculations (calculating the mean, standard deviation, covariance and correlation) will be meaningless. Something like Cramer's V indeed is appropriate here.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to change to `strings` to `integers`.

So for example:
`male=1`, `female=0` and `smoker=1` or `smoker=0` (for `yes` or `no`).

Here is an example with just the two relevant columns:

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'sex':['male','female','female','female','female'], 'smoke':[1,0,0,0,0], 'hello':[1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# example of how to convert sex from string to numeric
df['sex'] = df['sex'].apply(lambda r: 1 if r=='male' else 0)

c = df[['sex','smoke']].corr()
print(c)
```

The output:

```
       sex  smoke
sex    1.0    1.0
smoke  1.0    1.0
```

In this simple example case 100% correlated (because of the data).

Comment: Will this method works for **nominal** categorical variables?

Comment: @bhukkad_monk,  yes it will to the extent that you are logical with the categories. For example, would it be logical to seek a correlation between hair colour (which is categorical) and height (which is nominal) ?  However, his would not be in the scope of answering the programatic side, which is done with the above...

Comment: This would of course have no meaning as a coefficient because the values you assign are arbitrary.

Comment: @ayhan,  exactly my point.  it depends on the data and how the authour of the question elects to interpret this and if that is a logical intrpretation.  In terms of the question, a correlation is produced...